# View documentation of overridden method in PyCharm

Tags: methods, documentation, shortcut, pycharm

I have a python class in PyCharm containing an overriding method and want to see its documentation as quickly as possible. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the method name and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. This will work if you are using the default keymapping (see in File->Settings, Keymap, "Quick Documentation") or set the keymap yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> after placing your cursor on it.

Comment: Hi Games, Inspection (Ctrl+Shift+I) shows only the source code of the overriding method and not the docs of the overriden method. Check my answer below.